# How to collect data python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to collect the data with python using beautifulsoup but it is collecting all the data except emails data so how I can collect the emails also as well.

```
def scrapeProfileData(profilePageSource):
    time.sleep(6)
    try:
        personName = str(profilePageSource.find("title").get_text().encode("utf-8"))[2:-1]
    except:
        personName =""


    try:
        industry = str(profilePageSource.find("dd", class_="industry").get_text().encode("utf-8"))[2:-1]
    except:
        industry = ""
    try:
        location = str(profilePageSource.find("span", class_="locality").get_text().encode("utf-8"))[2:-1]
    except:
        location = ""
    try:
        title = str(profilePageSource.find("p", class_="title").get_text().encode("utf-8"))[2:-1]
    except:
        title = ""
    try:
        email = str(profilePageSource.find("@", class_="contact-field").get_text().encode("utf-8"))[2:-1]
    except:
        email = ""
        pass
```

Here is the table I'm trying to collect the data

```
dd class="industry"><a href="/vsearch/p?f_I=43&amp;trk=prof-0-ovw-industry" name="industry" title="Find other members in this industry">Financial Services</a></dd>

<span class="locality"><a href="/vsearch/p?f_G=gb%3A4573&amp;trk=prof-0-ovw-location" name='location' title="Find other members in London, Greater London, United Kingdom">London, Greater London, United Kingdom</a></span>

<p class="title">&#x2714;&#x2714;Sales &amp; Business Development Mobile Payments, Telecoms, Cloud&#x2714;&#x2714;</p>

<table summary="Online Contact Info"><tr><th>Email</th><td><div id="email"><div id="email-view"><ul><li><a href="mailto:username@domain.com">username@domain.com</a></li></ul></div>
```

I am thinking about to collect emails as well but is there need suggestion how I can..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to the email element using the following [`CSS selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
div#email-view a[href]
```

And, in the Python code:

```
email = profilePageSource.select("div#email-view a[href]")[0].get_text()
```

Or, alternatively, without a CSS selector using `find()`:

```
email = profilePageSource.find("div", id="email-view").a.get_text()
```